# ajax calling C# method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to call C# method using jquery ajax, the method doesn't return any thing instead it directly modifies the data in aspx page. My call is working perfectly alright but I am unable to make any changes to an UI from that method.

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                data: "{}",
                    <%--contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",--%>
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("E");

                    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("Error");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("ror1");
                }
            })
            return false;
        });
    });  
</script>
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]

    public string ServerSideMethod(){        
       Label1.Text="Hi";
       return "Hi ajax call to C# method";
    }
```

Note: The changes that has to be implemened in function only and if i remove the commented part in the javascript then the ajax calling throwing me the Error alert message

Comment: replace `alert("E");` with `console.log(msg.d)`, do you get anything in the console?

Comment: your comment _if i remove the commented part..._. Then the answer is correct because your ajax needs to get an object from your controller and you are returning a string from there so that causes error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerSideMethod` should be declared `static`:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ServerSideMethod()
```

and you can't change `Label1.Text` from inside `ServerSideMethod` since it's `static`.

Answer (score 0):

The server-side code can't change anything client-side.

Normally, in a non-AJAX page request, the server-side code is running statements like:

```
Label1.Text="Hi";
```

in order to build the response to the client.  Once that response is sent, it's no longer under the server-side code's control.  Since you're making an AJAX request from an already-rendered page, you can't modify that page (that's already in the browser) from the server.

Instead, you should render the response to the AJAX call and use JavaScript code to modify the page that's in the browser.

You're not showing the markup, so I can only guess what the selector would be.  But if `Label1` renders a `span` and uses the same `id` client-side then it might look like this:

```
$('#Label1').text('Hi');
```

This would be in the success callback of your AJAX call.  Something like this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    alert("E");
    $('#myDiv').text(msg.d);

    $('#Label1').text('Hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to uncomment your line in javascript code and add ScriptMethod attribute in your WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)
public string ServerSideMethod(){        
   //Label1.Text="Hi";
   return "Hi ajax call to C# method";
}
```

And why you have Label1.Text = "Hi" ? It's impossible in a WebMethod.